# Google Sheets - Find first occurrence of two unique values combined

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to execute as shown in the following google sheet link. I need to locate the first occurrence of two unique values in column H and I combined and input the Ratings as in the table.

[Sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jjuTLYp5c1rAPovR3b8DSAZmrc_0goEcV_IRGSbkEkw/)

My efforts have been displayed in the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS(H2:H&I2:I, H2:H&I2:I, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(H2:H&I2:I, SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&{B1, D1}&"×"&{C2:C, E2:E}), "×"), 2, )), ))
```

[image]